# parse.com – Cancel scheduled push programmatically

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I need to cancel some of scheduled push notifications via API.
Not via web console.

For example, it will be good to have ability to cancel all of scheduled push notifications for specific deviceToken (filter by deviceToken will be good enough, because I don’t need to cancel specific pushes).

REST API doc have nothing on this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment, the only two ways are to either use the Push Dashboard in a browser, which can be unhandy if you schedule a huge amount of notifications or to implement your own queuing system for Push notifications.

The latter would involve creating a new table for your notifications and a background job that will send out all notifications that are due to be sent. Once sent, remove them from that table.

Other than that, you're out of luck at the moment.